# Change color of selection in Android Studio editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, editor

How can I change the color of a selected text in the Android Studio Editor?
I want to change only the color highlight of the selected line(s) in Android Studio and not the overall background.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Editor -> Colors and Fonts -> General, then change the "Selection Background" setting. See below:

[image: Image showing preferences panel]

Make sure you apply your changes; then you should see them reflected both in the preferences window and in your live code:

[image: Image showing applied background color]

Answer (score 7):

## For Android Studio Version 3.2

This is the same answer as [the earlier accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32807534/624814), but updated because of recent changes to Android Studio (ok, Android is a moving target, but here's the latest as of November 2018).

**Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Editor -> Selection Background**

Then click on the hexadecimal block to the right of "Background" to pull up a color chooser.